# STM32F407 ADC setup problem: ADC sampling continues despite delay in code loop

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, adc, embedded, sampling

I'm trying to control the sampling rate with a delay function. I'm using channel 0 on ADC at PA0. This is how I've set it up:

```
void configure_ADC2_Channel_0(void) {
  //__HAL_RCC_ADC2_CLK_ENABLE(); // enable clock to ADC2 module
  myADC2Handle.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  myADC2Handle.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  myADC2Handle.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  myADC2Handle.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  myADC2Handle.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  myADC2Handle.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  myADC2Handle.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  myADC2Handle.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  myADC2Handle.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  myADC2Handle.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  myADC2Handle.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  HAL_ADC_Init(&myADC2Handle); // initialize AD2 with myADC2Handle configuration settings
    
  /*select ADC2 channel */
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef Channel_AN0; // create an instance of ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef
  Channel_AN0.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0; // select analog channel 0
  Channel_AN0.Rank = 1; // set rank to 1
  // Channel_AN0.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES; // set sampling time to 15 clock cycles
  HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&myADC2Handle, &Channel_AN0); // select channel_0 for ADC2 module. 
}
```

The problem is that despite however much delay I give it, it keeps sampling. I know the delay is working because the delay seems to apply to the onboard LEDs but not the ADC.

I'm somehow getting the thing to sample cleanly upto 1+ MHz despite the delay indicating a sampling rate of around 10k. I use a custom delay function for delaying in μs but even the HAL delay doesn't seem to deter the ADC.

I've tried enabling and disabling the conversion mode thing in this setting but it doesn't seem to be of much use.

ADC code looks like this :

```
        HAL_ADC_Start(&myADC2Handle); // start A/D conversion
        if(HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&myADC2Handle, 5) == HAL_OK) //check if conversion is completed
        {
        Adc_value  = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&myADC2Handle); // read digital value and save it inside uint32_t variable
        }
        HAL_ADC_Stop(&myADC2Handle); // stop conversion 
        x[20] = Adc_value;
        
    HAL_DAC_SetValue(&DAC_Config, DAC_CHANNEL_2, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R, (int)y);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14);
    delay_us(500) (Does not matter if replaced with HAL_Delay);
```

Delay code (c file)

```
#include "TA_STM32_Delay_Us.h"


/**
 * @brief  Initializes DWT_Clock_Cycle_Count for DWT_Delay_us function
 * @return Error DWT counter
 *         1: clock cycle counter not started
 *         0: clock cycle counter works
 */
uint32_t Delay_Us_Init(void) {
  /* Disable TRC */
  CoreDebug->DEMCR &= ~CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk; // ~0x01000000;
  /* Enable TRC */
  CoreDebug->DEMCR |=  CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk; // 0x01000000;

  /* Disable clock cycle counter */
  DWT->CTRL &= ~DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk; //~0x00000001;
  /* Enable  clock cycle counter */
  DWT->CTRL |=  DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk; //0x00000001;

  /* Reset the clock cycle counter value */
  DWT->CYCCNT = 0;

     /* 3 NO OPERATION instructions */
     __ASM volatile ("NOP");
     __ASM volatile ("NOP");
  __ASM volatile ("NOP");

  /* Check if clock cycle counter has started */
     if(DWT->CYCCNT)
     {
       return 0; /*clock cycle counter started*/
     }
     else
  {
    return 1; /*clock cycle counter not started*/
  }
}
```

Delay code, headerfile

```
#ifndef TA_STM32_DELAY_US_H
#define TA_STM32_DELAY_US_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

/**
 * @brief  Initializes DWT_Cycle_Count for DWT_Delay_us function
 * @return Error DWT counter
 *         1: DWT counter Error
 *         0: DWT counter works
 */
uint32_t Delay_Us_Init(void);



/**
 * @brief  This function provides a delay (in microseconds)
 * @param  microseconds: delay in microseconds
 */
__STATIC_INLINE void delay_us(volatile uint32_t microseconds)
{
  uint32_t clk_cycle_start = DWT->CYCCNT;

  /* Go to number of cycles for system */
  microseconds *= (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq() / 1000000);

  /* Delay till end */
  while ((DWT->CYCCNT - clk_cycle_start) < microseconds);
}


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: Where's the code with the delay? How is the delay implemented? Does it also "delay" peripherals? How can you tell the ADC is sampling when your main code is "delayed"? Where and how is `HAL_ADC_Start` called? You may want to show the complete code.

Comment: @ocrdu I've edited the question, I'm not sure whether the specific implementation of the delay is the problem since im getting the same weirdness with HAL_Delay so I didn't think it necessary to post. I'm not sure how to get the delay to the peripherals.

Comment: I can tell sampling is still going on because regardless of the delay, even 1ms delay gives me a cleanly samplined sinewave at 1Mhz on oscope

Comment: It looks like your delay function is a while loop. Why do you think that would change the ADC sampling rate? You set the ADC clock to a specific value, shouldn't it keep that value even if the CPU encounters a while loop?

Comment: Are you sure you are not seeing aliasing of your signal? Can you check if you get expected frequency from your measurements. For example set your signal source to 7 kHz and see if you get 3 kHz signal (this indicate aliasing and your code works correctly).

Comment: @Rokta I'm not sure now that the ADC code even works, when I remove HAL_ADC_Getvalue(), I still get an analog reading at pin PA5 which is configured as DAC output. I'm getting the exact same sinwave I put in PA0.  I just connected function generator to PA0 and tried to mirror adc_value via HAL_DAC_SetValue(). So the sinewave is passing through the whole thing without going into ADC, explain the peak-to-peak voltage of some 200 mV instead of DAC range. Not sure what to do about this now

Comment: @user1850479 Now do I do single mode conversion then ? ie Just read value at ADC only when I ask it to .I Think something is wrong with my ADC code since it doesn't look like it sampled the sinewave even from above comment.